# Mapping MySql views to JPA Entitites, which unique id to use?

Tags: mysql, jpa, view

So I'v been using views instead of result queries as entities in my project and I know I'm not alone, so, my question:

What do you use to act as and @Id when working with views? Sometime the answer to that question will be trivial, but sometimes when you don't have a unique field that stands out, what do you guys do?

Right now I'm including more fields that I need in a particular view, so I can have a mix of fields that are unique together, and I use the @Id annotation on each of those, and so far it's been working great.

It seems to be so contextual, I'v been asking myself if there is a more standard way of doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a standard way, but here is the approach that seems worths trying .

Idea is to generate unique "id" values (analog of rownum ) on the fly for the view . A bit modified version of function from [Create a view with column num_rows - MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15891993/create-a-view-with-column-num-rows-mysql) (modification done in order to reset rownum):

```
delimiter //

CREATE FUNCTION `func_inc_var_session`( val int) RETURNS int
    NO SQL
    NOT DETERMINISTIC
     begin
        if val = 0 THEN set @var := -1; end if;
      SET @var := IFNULL(@var,0) + 1;
      return @var;
     end
     //
```

Say we have a view definition (oversimplified for illustration purposes)

```
CREATE VIEW v_test1 
SELECT a.field1 
FROM test_table a
```

Modifying it to

```
CREATE VIEW v_test1 
SELECT a.field1,  func_inc_var_session(0) as rownum 
FROM test_table a
```

would do the job; however, running `select * from v_test` within one session multiple times will give you sequential rownums, e.g. first time it starts with 1, second time with number of records in the view, etc.

To reset rownum I create another view (because of mysql view limitation - it cannot have subquery in `FROM` ) :

`CREATE VIEW v_reset AS SELECT func_inc_var_session(1) ;`

Now we can do

```
CREATE VIEW v_test1 
SELECT a.field1,  func_inc_var_session(0) as rownum 
FROM test_table a, v_reset
```

(FROM clause processed first, `func_inc_var_session(1)` will be executed just once during the query, so it will reset rownum) .

I hope it helps.

Comment: It does actually, I will give this method a try later. Should've mentionned that I have way more java knowledge than anything related to SQL be it MySQL or anything else. Still, I found the "lack" of rownum in MySQL a bit annoying for this particular reason.

Answer (score 0):

Could not get the above code to work without the following changes.

CREATE VIEW v_test1
SELECT a.field1,  func_inc_var_session(***1***) as rownum
FROM test_table a

CREATE VIEW v_reset AS SELECT func_inc_var_session(***0***) ;

The main view (v_test1) needs to be reset to 1 each time. The v_reset function needs to be "reset" to zero (0) each time.